# Changing number formatting in excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

[image]

I have an Excel file that looks like this. How would I change the cell formatting so that it looks exactly like it does it the function bar.  Instead of `3E-07` --> `0.000003`

I don't want to change the decimal places because I only want it to have the number of decimal places it needs so there won't be extra zeroes at the end. 
For example because the smallest numbers have 7 decimal places if I change the whole column to seven decimal places numbers like 6E-05 will have two extra zeroes (0.0000600) at the end.

I'm trying to do this on macro because there are a lot of numbers to go through. I can set up the loop myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix on all columns, follow below steps:-

1. Click on the symbol mentioned side of **A column** (That is left side of A)
2. When you click on that symbol, it will select whole sheet
3. Double Click on border line between **A column** & **B column**
4. This is fix all your problems on the excel sheet

This number format issue is occurred due to column size.

To fix this type of number format **"0.0000600"**:-

1. select the Column header (that is A column, B column .. and soon which ever column you need to format)
2. Right click on the tab
3. Select **"Format Cell"**
4. Click on **custom** option under **Category**
5. under **Type** field, enter **0.0000000000**

Then it fix your format issue.

Comment: hey thank you. i didnt realize my problem was with access and not excel >.>. i guess this calls for posting another question to do with access. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this question with <kbd>VBA</kbd> so here are two examples of VBA's [.AutoFit method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223697%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

For the entire worksheet:

```
    With ActiveSheet    'set this worksheet reference more defintively!
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
```

If you have columns that are already the width you want you could test the first 20 rows to see if the [.TEXT property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) is displaying the hash mark (e.g. # or Chr(35)) symbol.

```
    With ActiveSheet    'set this worksheet reference properly!
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                For r = 1 To 20     'maybe even .Rows.Count for smaller data grids
                    If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(r, c).Text, Chr(35), vbBinaryCompare)) Then
                        .Columns(c).EntireColumn.AutoFit
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next r
            Next c
        End With
    End With
```

The latter defined the range of cells to work on using the [.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) which expands from its origin until it meets a fully blank row and column.